# Generalized Fibonacci Sequences with Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the following generalized fibonacci sequence:

For $m,p$ positive integers and $g_k =g_k (mod m)$, then for $n=1,2,3,...$ $g_{n+p}=g_{n+(p-1)}+g_{n+(p-2)}+...+g_{n+1}+g_n (modm)$

I need to prove that for $m>2$ and $p{>=} m$, $g_{n+p}$ is periodic with period $per<=m^p-1$

Can someone help me with this or point me to some material over this generalized sequence? I am confused on the starting of the sequence.. does it always just start with 1's? Can it be any beginning such that $g_1,g_2,...,g_{p-1}$ is $(modm)$? Won't the period depend on the starting?

Here is a problem that my professor provided and I've already proven:

$m=2,p=2$ with $g_1=1,g_2=1$ then $g_{n+2}=g_{n+1}+g_n (modm)$ and is $1,1,0,1,1,0...$ thus it is periodic with $per=3$

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The object is to prove the sequence is periodic with some fixed period $j \leq m^p-1$ no matter what the first $p$ terms are.

Comment: Well I understand that, but I am trying to get a feel for it by doing some examples.. I guess I'm just stuck

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** The pigeonhole principle, in the space $S = (\Bbb{Z}_m)^p - (0,0,0\ldots)$ shows that the sequence must return to a prior state of the last $p$ g's in at most the number of points available in $S$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with this principle. I will take a look and go from there!

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here but.... if I set $f(g_n)=g_{n+p}$. Say there are $m^p$ possible p-sets (finite set of the sequence) in the series.
Then by the pigeonhole principle, the sequence obtained by f is eventually periodic. But, since $f^{-1}$ exists such that $f^{-1}(g_{n+p})=g_n$ then $f$ is periodic with period at most the number of possible p-sets. Therefore $per<=(Z_m)^p-(0,0,0...)=m^p-1$
Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: Thank you! Any thoughts for if I set $m=2$? Now the period is $p+1$.. I have already proven for when $p=2$ but when I tried to explore for $p=3$ I got periods of $1,2,4$ depending on how I started the sequence.. So this could potentially be a "max period" rather than a rule?